# The import com.sun.javadoc cannot be resolved in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, javadoc, compiler-errors

I'm having problem compiling a project in Eclipse.

```
The import com.sun.javadoc cannot be resolved
```

I added tools.jar as an external jar, changed default compiler to use jdk instead of jre, did Project -> Clean afterwards. But nothing of this helped. What am I missing here?

**UPD:** this is how it looks like (packages exist on the left, but not seen on the right):
[alt text http://3593.iz.piccy.info.nyud.net/i5/93/35/353593/lol.gif](http://3593.iz.piccy.info.nyud.net/i5/93/35/353593/lol.gif)

Comment: Note:  If you add the JDK as a Java Runtime, and switch to it, the tools.jar should automatically be a part of the runtime libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo.
If you're attempting to run [javadoc programmatically](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/javadoc/standard-doclet.html#runningprogrammatically), you need to use

> com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main

and not

> com.sun.javadoc.Main.

Comment: I added a screenshot. Also, it's actually not my code, It's from an android platform sources. I also succeeded in building this code from the console, so the problem has to be somewhere in eclipse.

Comment: Ah Android, I believe its got something to do with the paths involved, as quite a few people have experienced the same - https://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/ee575553996a1c8b/f2eb29f955b1f523 ; you can try setting the ANDROID_JAVA_HOME variable, like discussed and verify if that works.

Comment: Btw, I'm behind a very restricted proxy, so apologies for not making anything out of the picture.

Comment: Yes, the problem was with android. Copied `/development/ide/eclipse/.classpath` to the root, and it resolved this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably because there are 'restriction' rules on the jar you are importing.

These can be disabled by disabling them. Either globally or just on the necessary project.

Should be something like:-

1. Right click on project
2. Select 'Project Properties'
3. Select page 'Java Compiler->Error/Warnings'
4. Enable project specific settings
5. Deprecated and restricted API->Forbidden reference (access rules). ---> set to 'ignore'